# mysql bad query performance inconsistent

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query which runs in 25 seconds on one machine, and 0.00 seconds on another.

EDIT - simply upgrading mysql fixed this. Leaving question for historical purposes.

explain extended shows it pulling 2084 rows on the first line on the bad system, and 1 or 2 rows on all the other ... steps? On the good system they are all 1 to 3 rows.

The slow query is happening on a virtual instance (AWS) with mysql version 5.5.56 and has row_format=COMPACT.

I pulled the whole db over to my system with mysqldump. It is a more powerful desktop, mysql version 5.7.22, row_format=DYNAMIC after the import.

The table structure is a pretty basic foreign key setup for "batch has transactions" and "transactions have items" and "items have itemexceptions".

This is the query (accumulation query auto-generated from django models)

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT `decision_batch`.`id`)
    FROM  `decision_batch`
    INNER JOIN  `decision_transaction`
            ON (`decision_batch`.`id` = `decision_transaction`.`batch_id`)
    INNER JOIN  `decision_item`
            ON (`decision_transaction`.`id` = `decision_item`.`transaction_id`)
    WHERE  `decision_item`.`id` IN (
        SELECT  U0.`id`
            FROM  `decision_item` U0
            INNER JOIN  `decision_transaction` U1
                 ON (U0.`transaction_id` = U1.`id`)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  `decision_itemexception` U2
                 ON (U0.`id` = U2.`item_id`)
            WHERE  U1.`batch_id` IN (2266)
            GROUP BY  U0.`id`, U0.`transaction_id`, U0.`item_type`,
                      U0.`sequence`, U0.`applied_amount`, U0.`accept`
            ORDER BY  NULL  );
```

Explain extended shows a "dependent subquery" on the bad system, but it's "simple" all the way down on the good system:

```
| id | select_type        | table                | type  | possible_keys       | key                             | key_len | ref                              | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | decision_batch       | index | PRIMARY       | decision_batch_c81d214          | 4       | NULL                             | 2084 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | decision_transaction | ref   | PRIMARY,decision_transaction_58f424c5,batch_transaction,transaction_accept | transaction_accept              | 4       | cloudbox.decision_batch.id       |    3 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | decision_item        | ref   | decision_item_45d19ab3       | decision_item_45d19ab3          | 4       | cloudbox.decision_transaction.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | U1                   | ref   | PRIMARY,decision_transaction_58f424c5,batch_transaction,transaction_accept | decision_transaction_58f424c5   | 4       | const                            |    2 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | U0                   | ref   | decision_item_45d19ab3       | decision_item_45d19ab3          | 4       | cloudbox.U1.id                   |    1 |   100.00 |                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | U2                   | ref   | decision_itemexception_67b70d25,item       | decision_itemexception_67b70d25 | 4       | cloudbox.U0.id                   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index    |    3 |   100.00 | Using index; End temporary   |
```

And in case it helps, show create table output (data lines omitted)

decision_batch

```
CREATE TABLE `decision_batch` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `decision_batch_c81d214` (`box_id`),
KEY `decision_batch_1c65f4ce` (`finalized_by_id`),
KEY `dec_opt_idx` (`finalized`,`batch_status`,`box_id`),
CONSTRAINT `decision_batch_ibfk_1`
       FOREIGN KEY (`box_id`) REFERENCES `lockbox_lockbox` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `finalized_by_id_refs_id_31bb6e9b`
       FOREIGN KEY (`finalized_by_id`) REFERENCES `config_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2267 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

decision_transaction

```
CREATE TABLE `decision_transaction` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`batch_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `decision_transaction_58f424c5` (`batch_id`),
KEY `batch_transaction` (`id`,`batch_id`),
KEY `transaction_accept` (`batch_id`,`accept`),
CONSTRAINT `batch_id_refs_id_24828b6d`
       FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `decision_batch` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19306 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

decision_item

```
CREATE TABLE `decision_item` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `decision_item_45d19ab3` (`transaction_id`),
CONSTRAINT `transaction_id_refs_id_56c7fe1d`
       FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `decision_transaction` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45544 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

decision_itemexception

```
CREATE TABLE `decision_itemexception` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `decision_itemexception_67b70d25` (`item_id`),
KEY `item` (`item_id`),
KEY `field` (`field_id`),
CONSTRAINT `field`
       FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `decision_field` (`id`)
           ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `item`
       FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `decision_item` (`id`)
           ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44589 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: currently upgrading the lower version of mysql to see if that resolves it

Comment: This query should in theory return either 0 or 1 - depending on whether there are transactions for the batch with ID of 2266. And it could be definitely simplified to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yes, it is one of several django one-liners that make up a summary report. (several of them have performance hits, but run instantly for me, locally)

Comment: This query seems to do a lot of things which are not needed to get the result. E.g. you may replace 'WHERE decision_item.id IN` with `WHERE batch_id IN (2266)` and get rid of the subquery

Comment: Actually, I can bypass that query entirely if there is only one batch in the query. Thanks. However, there are several other simple reporting queries that are similar, and which I may not be able to skip.

Comment: Perhaps you can manually rewrite them in a way which is beyond the capabilities of Django? Removing the needless work will certainly help to improve the performance.

Comment: Upgrading the mysql version fixed the slow queries. Additionally, I am skipping some of the problem queries entirely, in case it is run on an older mysql again. I would say "how do I get django to give me custom queries" but that would be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: You are comparing different mysql versions that have different internal optimisations. Looks like 5.5 does not have some optimisations that 5.7 has and that makes the query fast in the last case. 

You can try to upgrade server or re-write the query.

I've found your query a bit strange.
I do not see any reason for putting where into inner query and have the left join, group by and order by there.

Comment: Hey, that's autogenerated by a really old django version. I don't have a lot of control over that, but I can skip this particular one entirely if the batch count is 1 coming in, as it usually is.

Comment: The Optimizer has made a number of improvements since 5.5.  If you would like to investigate the changes further, we need to look at the old `EXPLAIN`.